# How to read and instert name, price data field from firestore to website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have made an e-commercial website, so when people click add to cart it will store firestore(name, price, etc..),

but I need to read the saved data on another page ( by using firestore read data). anybody can help me with this

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.